# Unpacking structure to l-value tuple in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, tuples

I have following structure:

```
struct Pixel{x:f64, y:f64, dx:f64, dy:f64}
```

I got this structure as argument into function. I want to reduce typing and unpack it:

```
fn foo(pixel:Pixel){
    let (x, y, dx, dy) = pixel;
}
```

This code does not compile. Are there any syntax sugar to avoid endless `pixel.x`, `pixel.dx`, etc? I want to have some easy way to 'extract' ( to alias) values of structure into my function. And I want to avoid verbosity of `let x = pixel.x; let dx = pixel.dx`, etc.

Is there a concise way to do it?

Comment: I need to use individual values in formulae a lot, and I want to avoid repeating `pixel.` part. Example `central_x=pixel.x+pixel.dx/2.0` (it looks better in form of `central_x = x + dx/2.0`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An attentive reading of [chapter 18 of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs) is recommended here. One can use pattern matching to destructure arrays, enums, structs, and tuples.

```rust
let Pixel { x, y, dx, dy } = pixel;
```

This can even be employed in a function's parameter arguments.

```rust
fn foo(Pixel { x, y, dx, dy }: Pixel) {

}
```